# CSS3 zoom image to center of container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a gallery. When an image is clicked it is supposed to zoom in to center of view. Right now the click event will give the image this class:

```
.imgFocus
{
    transition  : All 1s ease;
    transform   : scale(2); 
}
```

That looks fine and the image zooms in. But I want it to zoom in to the center of the container, no matter where the image is to begin with.

Like this (mockup):

```
.imgFocus
{
    transition: All 1s ease;
    transform: translate( 'containerCenter' ) scale(2); 
}
```

Is there any good way of doing that?

Comment: Is this zooming as you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/kvTNZ/

Comment: Yes. The scale-thing works just like I want it to. Just that I want the transform to also put the image in the center of the container.

Comment: You mean the upper left corner of the image should be at the center of  its container ? or the center of the image should be at the center of its container ?

Comment: The center should be at the center. Kind of like a lightbox, but I only want to use trasition.

Comment: It's already centered, I don't know what you mean. What browser are you using ? do you have some extra css? please provide a jsfiddle or some code.

Comment: It is centered to itself, but I want the img to find the center of the containing element - or possibly the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **div** and set it to have a **background-image**. Using CSS set the background-position for that **div** to **center**. From there you should be able to create a zoom-in zoom-out effect without it offsetting. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

some solutions

- add transform-origin:50% 50%;-moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;-ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; to the img
- add background-image + background-position:50% 50% + background-size 200% 200% + relative to the container & remove the img